# Trouble executing indefinite loops in Gforth

Tags: loops, forth, gforth

What would be the correct style to represent an input such as the one below in Gforth?

```
while (2 > 1) {1 + 1}
```

With my current understanding from resources online, it should be:

```
: loop begin 2 @ 1 > while 1 1 + repeat
```

However when I do try and interpret this with Gforth I get an error:

```
 expected dest, do-dest or scope
 : >>>loop<<< begin 2 @ 1 > while 1 1 + repeat
```

Comment: `: loop begin 2 1 > while 1 1 + drop repeat ;` — but it doesn't have much sense.

Comment: How does this in compliance with forth loop syntax:
  
"BEGIN code1 flag WHILE code2 REPEAT. "

Is "2 1 >" the flag and " 1 1 +" code 2? What is code 1 and why is drop being using in this example?

Comment: You have to learn the very basics, try some tutorials: [Easy Forth](https://skilldrick.github.io/easyforth/), [Simple Forth](http://www.murphywong.net/hello/simple.htm).

Comment: Please can you help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040227/gforth-conditional-expression-with-variables-only-partly-correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four problems with the code you posted:

- You redefine `loop` to something else.  Maybe better to name it something else.
- I don't see a `;` to end the colon definition.
- You use `@` with something that is not an address.  Just drop `@`.  `2 1 >` will return true.
- `1 1 +` pushes a result to the stack, but you don't consume it.  Thus the stack will overflow.

I would suggest this:

```
: infinite   begin 2 1 > while 1 1 + drop repeat ;
```

Which is almost exactly what ruvim posted in a comment.