# Gforth conditional expression with variables - only partly correct

Tags: forth, gforth

Simple expression:

```
variable x  ok
4 x !  ok
3 x < . -1  ok
3 x > . 0  ok
```

This seems normal and correct, however:

```
variable x  ok
3 x !  ok
x 4 < . 0  ok
x 4 > . -1  ok
```

The second block of code is wrong. What is evaluating wrongly? What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`variable x` makes a new variable, but `x` returns the address, not the value.

You need something like this:

```
variable x
3 x !  ok
x @ 4 < .
x @ 4 > .
```